# Why am I getting this "IndexError: string index out of range" in one case but not the other?

Tags: python

```
#i couldnt find the difference in the code 
    >>> def match_ends(words):
     # +++your code here+++
     count=0
     for string in words:
      if len(string)>=2 and string[0]==string[-1]:
       count=count+1
     return count

>>> match_ends(['', 'x', 'xy', 'xyx', 'xx'])
2
>>> 
>>> def match_ends(words):
    # +++your code here+++
     count=0
     for string in words:
      if string[0]==string[-1] and len(string)>=2:
       count=count+1
     return count

>>> match_ends(['', 'x', 'xy', 'xyx', 'xx'])

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
   match_ends(['', 'x', 'xy', 'xyx', 'xx'])
   File "<pyshell#25>", line 5, in match_ends
   if string[0]==string[-1] and len(string)>=2:
   IndexError: string index out of range
```

I couldn't find the difference in the code except the if condition `if len(string)>=2 and string[0]==string[-1]:` in the first function   and  `if string[0]==string[-1] and len(string)>=2:` in the second function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first, you first check if there are enough characters to test against, in the second you don't:

```
if len(string)>=2 and string[0]==string[-1]:
```

and

```
if string[0]==string[-1] and len(string)>=2:
```

and pass in an *empty* string:

```
match_ends(['', 'x', 'xy', 'xyx', 'xx'])
```

The empty string has length 0, and no character at index 0:

```
>>> len('')
0
>>> ''[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The `if` boolean expression is being evaluated left-to-right, and the `string[0]==string[-1]` expression is evaluated before the `len(string)>=2` test, and then fails for that empty string.

In the other version, the `len(string)>=2` part is evaluated first, found to be `False` for the empty string (0 is not greater or equal to 2) and Python then doesn't need to look at the other half of the `and` expression at all, since there is no chance the `and` expression will become `True` whatever the second half evaluates to.

See [Boolean expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in the python documentation:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.