# want 24 hr format time in DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

My date and time are stored in database in 24 hr format.What i do is use a stored procedure to fetch the required date and times and insert in a datatable. But in the datatable it automatically converts in 12 hr format.After fetching data from datatable it is possible to convert it into 24hr pattern but it has to be converted into string.But the problem is that i need to use the data to create a chart which would only accept DateTime format.
So what i want is some way to convert 12 hr time to 24 hr time format without changing it to string.Please help.

Comment: `DateTime` struct has no format at all. It's just an info about date and time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518519/why-am-i-getting-this-indexerror-string-index-out-of-range-in-one-case-but-no

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My date and time are stored in database in 24 hr format.

I hope they're not actually stored in *any* text format, but instead in a `DateTime` field or something similar. Don't confuse "what I see when I run a SQL query" with "what's stored in the database." Just as numbers aren't stored as sequences of decimal digits, dates and times shouldn't be stored as text.

> But in the datatable it automatically converts in 12 hr format.

No, if you've done everything properly it should be storing everything in the `DataTable` as a `DateTime`. In the *debugger* you may see a 12-hour string representation, but the object itself should be a `DateTime`.

Basically the 12/24-hour problem is only a *symptom* of the real problem: unnecessary string conversions. Track *those* down (and remove them), and the rest should take care of itself. So if yo're currently calling `ToString()` when you extract the value from the `DataTable`, stop doing that. Instead, just cast:

```
DateTime dateTime = (DateTime) row["foo"];
```

Comment: thank  you for the reply...bt is there a way to convert a datetime in 12 hr format to 24 hr format without converting it to string(without changing its type).

Comment: @user1919448 DateTime objects aren't stored with any particular format in mind. You can get 24h format from any DateTime object like so: `string formatted24HourTime = myDateTime.ToString("HH:mm");`

Comment: I can't believe I downvoted a Jon Skeet answer, but if you read carefully, the data type in the DataTable is already a `DateTime`, so this rhetoric is unnecessary.

Comment: @Thorarin: If you read carefully, you'll see that I've said that: "No, if you've done everything properly it should be storing everything in the DataTable as a DateTime. In the debugger you may see a 12-hour string representation, but the object itself should be a DateTime." I'll add a clarification though. The point is that the OP shouldn't be thinking of the value as being "in 12 hour format" etc. I think the rhetoric is entirely necessary to clear up this misunderstanding.

Comment: @user1919448, you have to look at it like this. At date and time is a numeric offset from a well known point in time. It may be displayed a number of different ways - but it doesn't change the ***real value of the date and time*** regardless of that display.

Answer (score 2):

From your story, I understand that the `DataTable` actually contains a `DateTime` value, which **doesn't have any format** by itself, it basically just stores a number of ticks since an arbitrary date and time. What you are seeing in your table visualization is the default `ToString()` conversion, based on your application's culture settings.

Most likely, if you were to do something like this before running your existing code, the format would change:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

I would recommend converting to a format of your preference by calling [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) explictly however. How exactly you would best accomplish this depends on how you are visualizing the data from the `DataTable`.

Comment: Why do you believe a conversion to string is necessary at all? From the question: "But the problem is that i need to use the data to create a chart which would only accept DateTime format."

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not really sure what the issue is, but since OP was complaining about the format not being right, he must be displaying it in some way, I assumed.

Comment: I suspect the OP is converting to a string when getting the value out of the DataTable but without any actual need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

All that @Jon said is right.

But if you just explained yourself wrong, and you do have `DateTime` object in your db, and you are looking to format it into 24 hr **only when displaying** - you can use "HH" in string format for 24 hour format.

For example, for `myDateTime` representing 16:00:

```
var hourPart = String.Format("{0:HH}", myDateTime) 
Console.WriteLine(hourPart); // prints 16, and not 4PM.
```